# Hide div in Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Why is the jquery selector not working?

View

```
        Views.Now = Backbone.View.extend({
        template:"mytemplate",


        initialize:function () {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.find(".content").hide();  // selector is not working
        }

    });
```

Template:

```
<div id="now">
<p class="loader">Waiting for connection</p>
<div class="content">
    <button>hello world</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone views are only rendered after their render() method is called. Before that, the view's element will still be empty, so the selector won't find anything.

Comment: If you want the div.content to be hidden by default, the best way IMO would be to use CSS display:none. Another solution would be to call this.render() before the "find" selector to make sure the template is rendered. So your line would look like this: this.render().$el.find(".content").hide();

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
_.extend._configure.render